# Install old (unsupported) Android Version on unlocked smartphone

Tags: android, android-source, google-pixel

I would like to install an older Android version on a Pixel 3a. I saw the system images provided by Google, but they only offer Android9.0-10.0 ([see here](https://developers.google.com/android/images#sargo)). I already unlocked the bootloader, so I think I'm ready to start the flashing. For testing purposes I want to install Android5.0 and Android7.0.

Unfortunately, a virtual android device is not feasible for my use-case, this is why I have to run the version on the real device.

Now, I know that I can just go ahead and build these versions myself ([as described here](https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements)), but I'm not sure if this will work. Is the Pixel 3a compatible with Android versions that were never meant to run on it? And is there a faster way to just test boot different versions, by downloading the system image (just like with [this list](https://developers.google.com/android/images#sargo)). I saw forum entries, that stated, downloading the android source takes up to 24h...

Thanks for any hints! And tips for the general build procedure

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the proprietary blobs will not be compatible.